# Yii php x-editable, using remote source for select2 editable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, x-editable

[X-editable API](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) says I could use:

```
//remote source (simple)
$('#country').editable({
    source: '/getCountries',
    select2: {
        placeholder: 'Select Country',
        minimumInputLength: 1
    }
})
```

for defining select2 editable fields, with a remote source from `'/getCountries'`, but I'm really stuck where `getCountries` goes to. I know that editable works on ajax. Is this an ajax function in the controller?
If it is:

- How do I define the function and what should I put in the
  `'source:'`?
- How do I define the absolute Url where the list will be coming from? And how should the array be formatted?

Sorry I haven't exactly figured out the syntax of the editables. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should have something like:

```
public function actionGetCountries() {
    some code here
}
```

This code will gather all the countries (I guess from the db?) and return them as an array (for the select2 to be filled).

Answer (score 0):

```
//remote source (simple)
$('#country').editable({
    source: 'getCountries.php',
    select2: {
        placeholder: 'Select Country',
        minimumInputLength: 1
    }
})
```

create getCountries.php and put this inside:

```
<?php
$array = array(
               array("id"=>1,text=>"Great Britain"), 
               array("id"=>2,text=>"United States")
);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

**DONE!**